# populate the dropdown of an usercontrol before its value is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i have a usercontrol named ucTZones
Following is the code of the usercontrol.

```
public partial class ucTZones : UserControl{

        /// <summary>
        /// Accessor for the time zone drop-down.
        /// </summary>
        public int ddlProp
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return Int32.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    this.ddl.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.ddl.SelectedValue = "0";
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!ispostback)
              BindDropDown();

          }

        private void BindDropDown()
        {
          ddl.datasource =somelist;
          ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

This usercontrol is used in a page named TZonePage
On the page load event following code is written.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                 this.ucTZones.ddlProp=15;
            }
        }
```

Now my question is how can i populate the ddl of the usercontrol before the execution of 
following line of Page_Load of TZonePage

```
this.ucTZones.ddlProp=15;
```

Comment: Why don't you provide a property for the datasource of the `DropDownList`? Then the controller (the page) is responsible for the correct order and it's also more reusable.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Let me implement and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should not use `Page_Load` (or other page-methods) in a `UserControl` for the reason you've noticed. Instead you should use methods or properties in your UC where you trigger your logic. In this case you could also check in the property if the datasource is already loaded:

```
public int ddlProp
{
    get
    {
        if(ddl.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return -1;
        return int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
    }
    set
    {
         if(ddl.datasource== null)
             BindDropDown();
         if(ddl.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString()) != null)
             this.ddl.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
         else
             this.ddl.SelectedValue = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may check this, I didn't test it

```
public partial class ucTZones : UserControl{
            /// <summary>
            /// Accessor for the time zone drop-down.
            /// </summary>
            public int ddlProp
            {
                get
                {
                    // your variable to get the value
                }
                set
                {
                    // your variable to assign
                }
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(!ispostback)
                  BindDropDown();

              }

            private void BindDropDown()
            {
              ddl.datasource =somelist;
              ddl.DataBind();
ddl.SelectedValue = ddlProp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is what i mentioned in my question. where is the solution of it?

Comment: check the `BindDropDown()` function